# Login with Stack Exchange Id. JS/Ajax Issues

Tags: support, login

I logged in to Stack Overflow with my default dial-up internet connection, it works well. When I'm using proxies and I try to log in, I click the "Log in with your Stack Exchange account" the images disappear and this

[image: http://stackapps.com/content/img/progress-dots.gif]

^^ just shows ad infinitum. I honestly don't know why.

Can it be set to show a traditional login form, without the fancy dots. Right now I'm trying to log in to stack apps all I see is the 'load dots'

Comment: Even when I switch browsers, it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you see the same problem on other computers using the same network environments?

Comment: Yes. The same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pick a different identity provider in that case.

So:

1. Log in with whatever works (dial up? wtf?)
2. Open your user page
3. Click "my logins"
4. Click "add new login..."
5. Pick anything except Stack Exchange
6. Finish

Now you can log in with an alternate provider and bypass ours. Note that you can have an (effectively) infinite number of logins, so feel free to go ballistic and add as many as you want.

Comment: It works using Facebook Connect! Thanks